# Create a rectangular wave in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a sine wave and on the same plot, a DC wave which is the threshold voltage for an Op-Amp comparator without feedback.

The code I have written so far is:

```
t1 = 0:t/1000:N*t;
y1 = Vin*sin(2*(1/t)*3.14*t1);
subplot('position',[0.056 0.1 0.27 0.25]);
plot(t1,y1,t1,Vth, 'r');
grid on;
title('Input Signal');
xlabel('Time[s]');
ylabel('Vi');
```

My problem is that I need to make another plot in which I have a rectangular wave which changes from `Vin` to `-Vin` when the threshold is reached by the sine wave.

This is what I am trying to do:

[image]

I have tried everything I know in MATLAB to make that plot, but I still haven't managed to create it.  Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method would be to use the [Signum function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sign.html) through `sign` in conjunction with a sinusoidal function.

The [Signum function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) is used quite heavily in signal processing, especially in communication systems with the [Hilbert Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform).  The signum function is a sign indicator.  If the input into the function is positive, the output is 1, if the input is negative, the output is -1 and if the input is 0, the output is 0.  This very well simulates an operational amplifier with no feedback.  However, you want this to change sign when the threshold is reached.  Therefore, you would apply `sign` on the signal subtracted with this threshold.  Given that your input/output is scaled by `Vin`, you would need to scale the output of `sign` by `Vin` as well as the outputs are within the range of -/+ 1.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
Vth = 1; %// Threshold
Vin = 5; %// Amplitude of input/output
fs = 10; % // Hz
t = 0 : 0.001 : 0.5;
y = Vin*sin(2*pi*fs*t);
yout = Vin*sign(y - Vth);
plot(t, y, t, yout, [0 0.5], [Vth Vth]);
```

The above code declares a threshold of 1, the amplitude of the input being 5, followed by specifying a sinusoidal frequency, and a time vector from 0 to 0.5 seconds in steps of 0.001.  Next, we generate a sinusoidal signal, then generate the saturated wave with the threshold in use.  We plot the sinusoidal signal, the saturated signal as well as the threshold mark so you can see it working

This is what I get:

[image]

As you can see, the saturated wave changes polarity once the wave surpasses the threshold.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
y2 = Vin*(y1 >= thresh) + -Vin*(y1 < thresh)
```

When you do `y1 >= thresh`, you will have 1's where y1 > thresh, 0 otherwise (which you then multiply by `Vin`).  The opposite will happen for `-Vin`

This is what the output looks (albeit I did this in python but the syntax is the same) when superimposed.  Threshold was set to 2 here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
y2=y1;
y2(y2>=Vth)=Vin
y2(y2<Vth)=-Vin
```

To plot both:

```
subplot(2, 1, 1), plot(t1, y1);
subplot(2, 1, 2), plot(ti, y2);
```